# Newer Custom Installer library is not called during update?

Tags: windows-installer

In my VS 2010 setup project, I add custom actions by creating custom installer library. It works well.  However, when my custom installer requires new logic it is not called during an upgrade.  Even I change the version of custom installer library the setup still uses the older custom installer library. If I perform a new installation then setup uses the new custom installer library as expected.

Is this by design?

My setup is marked to remove previous version but it seems that the old custom library is already loaded into the installation process and continues to use it through out the upgrade process.

I check the installation folder and the new custom installer library is installed and the old has been removed but all of the logic is still in the old custom library.

I appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have this problem:

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2418919/en-us

because it has unpredictable effects. And I don't believe that this was ever fixed, despite it being VS 2005.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906766/en-us